# Re-use string that are using on pattern/matched/replace/split Spark function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file without a separator, it is like a shop ticket, most of the transactions begins with:

```
**25/11/2019 05:36:32    INSERTED**
```

But some no, I am trying to find a way to use that string as a separator and at the same time I am trying to still using it that data adding a "|" to separate records.

Original:

```
**25/11/2019 05:36:32    INSERTED (Some transactions) 25/11/2019 05:38:32    INSERTED (Some trans) 25/11/2019 05:42:32    INSERTED**
```

Goal:

```
**25/11/2019 05:36:32    INSERTED (Some transactions) |25/11/2019 05:38:32    INSERTED (Some trans) |25/11/2019 05:42:32    INSERTED**
```

But I get:

```
** (Some transactions) | (Some trans) |**
```

The last function that I used was:

```
val vStringRDD = stringRDD.map{x => x.split("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}[ ]{1}[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[ ]{4}INSERTED").mkString("|")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regex replace and insert to re-use string that is using on pattern/matched/replace/split.

str.replaceAll( (regex1)(regex2), "$1 insert $2")

```
val vStringRDD = stringRDD.map { x =>
  println(s"Map: $x")
  val o = x.replaceAll("()([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}[ ]{1}[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[ ]{1}INSERTED)", "$1 | $2")
  println(s"Output: $o")
  o
}

//Output
Map: 25/11/2019 05:36:32 INSERTED (Some transactions) 25/11/2019 05:38:32 INSERTED (Some trans) 25/11/2019 05:42:32 INSERTED
Output:  | 25/11/2019 05:36:32 INSERTED (Some transactions)  | 25/11/2019 05:38:32 INSERTED (Some trans)  | 25/11/2019 05:42:32 INSERTED
```

Comment: Thank you, It was really helpful.